# Tkinter : How to center the window title

Tags: python, tkinter, title, centering

I am creating a project using tkinter and when I create a window, I couldn't seem to get the window title to center itself (Like most programs nowadays). Here's the example code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Window Title".center(110))# Doesn't seem to work

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to center the window title up ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you can do. Tkinter has no control over how the window manager or OS displays the titles of windows other than to specify the text.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a trick that does the job and it consists in simply adding as much blank space before the title:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("                                                                          Window Title")# Add the blank space
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=200, bg='yellow')
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a string consisting of an empty space and concatenate it to the title after multiplication. I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
blank_space =" " # One empty space
root.title(80*blank_space+"Window Title")# Easier to add the blank space 
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=200, bg='yellow')
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks ! But wouldn't that result differently depending on different monitor?

Comment: This assumes a fixed size window with a specific font. If the user changes the default system font or resizes the window, the title will no longer appear centered.

Comment: Well, tell me one single situation where this does not work.

Comment: You should have used couple of "\t"s instead

Answer (score 1):

More adding onto what Billal suggested is this example that adjust depending on the window size. I still wouldn't recommend it since it's just a hack for visual aesthetics but if you really want to have it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def center(e):
    w = int(root.winfo_width() / 3.5) # get root width and scale it ( in pixels )
    s = 'Hello Word'.rjust(w//2)
    root.title(s)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Configure>", center) # called when window resized
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this only works in very specific situations. In my case, it failed miserably. It really depends on how the os/window manager is configured. To do it right you need to get the font used by the window manager, compute the actual width of the title string based on that font, compute the width of a space, and then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Yea, I would not expect it to work in most situations or it would require more tweaking, I'm using windows 10. As stated it's not something I would suggest it's just there if the OP really wants it.

Answer (score 0):

```
width=root.winfo_screenwidth()
spacer=(" "*(int(width)//6))
root.title(spacer+"Your title")
```

This is not that much perfect but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a full stop or any special character at starting so that blank spaces are considered and then add blank spaces.

`title='UNI-CARD'root.title(f'.     {title}')`