# How can I make the title become in the center of the window using grid?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here's my code, I am still trying to make it show in the middle at the top of the page.

```
    TR= Tk()
    TR.geometry('600x600')

    TR.title('BEGINNER')

    title = Label(TR, text = 'CENTER', anchor = CENTER, justify = CENTER)

    title.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 20, sticky = N+S+E+W)
```

Comment: the `title()` module is specifically for the root window title. It is not something you can use as a label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a Tkinter widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736465/how-to-center-a-tkinter-widget)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter : How to center the window title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373621/tkinter-how-to-center-the-window-title)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think its actually a duplicate of [How to center the window title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373621/tkinter-how-to-center-the-window-title/38377381)

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear as to what your question is.

You cannot accurately center the actual window title however you can center the label.

Take a look at the below code.

```
from tkinter import *

TR= Tk()
TR.geometry('300x100')

TR.title('BEGINNER')
TR.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

Label(TR, text = 'CENTER').grid(row = 0, sticky = "ew")

TR.mainloop()
```

[image]

In case you are wanting to change the position of the actual window title there is another option that may sometimes work.

Please note the function is copied from and existing Q/A here [Tkinter : How to center the window title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373621/tkinter-how-to-center-the-window-title)

```
from tkinter import *

TR= Tk()
TR.geometry('300x100')

TR.title('BEGINNER')
TR.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

title = Label(TR, text = 'CENTER')
title.grid(row = 0, sticky = "ew")

def configure(event):
    w = int(TR.winfo_width() / 3.5)
    s = 'BEGINNER'.rjust(w//2)
    TR.title(s)

TR.bind("<Configure>", configure)

TR.mainloop()
```

As you can see from the below image it is not 100% center and it will shift around a bit when resizing. So this is probably not exactly what you want either. In general there is not an existing method you can use to accurately sit the title in the center of the window title bar.

[image]

There is one more option I can think of...
You could disable/hide the title bar and create your own title bar.
It wont look as nice most likely but you can center a label on it to act as the title bar.